# Counting by opening and closing dates

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R which gives me the date of opening and closing of every store in every town and region, like this:

```r
town <- c("A", "A", "A", "B")
opening <- as.Date(c("1900-01-01", "1905-02-05", "1906-01-01", "1910-01-01"))
closing <- as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, "1913-03-03"))

df <- data.frame(town, opening, closing)
```

I want to count the number of stores per town for each year (at the end of the year), corresponding each observation to a town and a year, so that I get this:

```r
town_final <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
year <- c(1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905, 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905)
stores <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)

df_final <- data.frame(town_final, year, stores)
```

I have a huge number of observations so I have to do this with loops, but I am unsure about how to do it correctly. I appreciate a lot any help.

Comment: The example outputs don't correspond to the inputs—e.g. town B has one store open from 1910-1913 in the inputs, but 1903-1904 in the outputs.

Comment: That’s true! Sorry, I was making some trials and I pasted the first try as the inputs but a different one in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tidyverse solution using a few tools worth getting to know:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# sample data
df <- tibble(
    town = c("A", "A", "A", "B"),
    opening = as.Date(c("1900-01-01", "1905-02-05", "1906-01-01", "1910-01-01")),
    closing = as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, "1913-03-03"))
)
```

First, we make a unique ID for each store, clean up the start and end years, and make sequences of integers from `year_opened` to `year_closed`:

```r
df_intermediate <- df %>% 
    mutate(
        # make a unique ID for to track each store
        store_id = uuid::UUIDgenerate(n = n()),
        # ceiling to New Years after opening and extract year
        year_opened = year(ceiling_date(opening, unit = 'year', change_on_boundary = FALSE)),
        # use current year for still-open stores, and extract year
        year_closed = year(coalesce(closing, Sys.Date())),
        # iterate in parallel over open and close years and make a sequence of open years for 
        # each row, in a list column
        open_years = map2(year_opened, year_closed, seq)
    )

df_intermediate
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>   town  opening    closing    store_id        year_opened year_closed open_years
#>   <chr> <date>     <date>     <chr>                 <dbl>       <dbl> <list>    
#> 1 A     1900-01-01 NA         55151ece-6295-…        1900        2023 <int>     
#> 2 A     1905-02-05 NA         7d34b1a6-86fe-…        1906        2023 <int>     
#> 3 A     1906-01-01 NA         9db13517-ed09-…        1906        2023 <int>     
#> 4 B     1910-01-01 1913-03-03 3c7af4e2-3ca2-…        1910        1913 <int [4]>
```

Then we subset to columns we need, unnest the list column to long form, and group and count distinct stores per town and year, and sort:

```r
df_out <- df_intermediate %>% 
    # subset to cols we care about and rename
    select(town, store_id, year = open_years) %>%
    # expand year list col, duplicating town and store_id for each year
    unnest(c(year)) %>% 
    group_by(town, year) %>%
    # count distinct stores open per town and year
    summarise(n_stores_open = n_distinct(store_id), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    # sort
    arrange(town, year)

df_out
#> # A tibble: 128 × 3
#>    town   year n_stores_open
#>    <chr> <int>         <int>
#>  1 A      1900             1
#>  2 A      1901             1
#>  3 A      1902             1
#>  4 A      1903             1
#>  5 A      1904             1
#>  6 A      1905             1
#>  7 A      1906             3
#>  8 A      1907             3
#>  9 A      1908             3
#> 10 A      1909             3
#> # ℹ 118 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learned some tools that I did not know and that seem pretty useful. The only problem I encounter is the dataset that I have is pretty long and  when I create open_years the vectors are really big, so that when I create the last dataset df_out I receive the following error Long vectors are not yet supported. Requested output size must be less than 2147483647. Any idea about how to deal with this?

Comment: You can make the result df directly (groups and years), and then subset to rows in that town where the store is open: `df_intermediate %>% group_by(town) %>% summarise(year = list(min(year_opened):max(year_closed))) %>% unnest(c(year)) %>% mutate(n = map2_int(town, year, function(t, y) df_intermediate %>% filter(town == t, y >= year_opened, y <= year_closed) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(store_id)) %>% pull(n)))` This runs once per row of `df_out`, which is potentially slow! But may be faster and less memory-intensive if the number of stores is huge.

Answer (score 0):

One potential {tidyverse} solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

town <- c("A", "A", "A", "B")
opening <- as.Date(c("1900-01-01", "1905-02-05", "1906-01-01", "1910-01-01"))
closing <- as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, "1913-03-03"))

df <- data.frame(town, opening, closing)
stores_open <- expand.grid(town_final = unique(town),
                           years = 1900:1905)

stores_open |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  left_join(df, by = c("town_final" = "town"), multiple = "all") |> 
  mutate(end_year = ymd(paste0(years, "1231")),
         closing = replace_na(closing, as.Date(Inf)),
         is_open = end_year >= opening & end_year <= closing) |> 
  group_by(town_final, years) |> 
  summarise(stores = sum(is_open))
```

The idea is essentially to check if each individual store is open on the last day of a given year, and stores as `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Then group by town and year, and add them up. This gives:

```r
# A tibble: 12 × 3
# Groups:   town_final [2]
   town_final years stores
   <chr>      <int>  <int>
 1 A           1900      1
 2 A           1901      1
 3 A           1902      1
 4 A           1903      1
 5 A           1904      1
 6 A           1905      2
 7 B           1900      0
 8 B           1901      0
 9 B           1902      0
10 B           1903      0
11 B           1904      0
12 B           1905      0
```

These values doesn't quite match the output you've asked for, but I'm not sure how you got e.g. 3 for 1903 in town A based on your input data provided.

Comment: Thanks! I have used this solution and it is really intuitive to me, but I don't know why when applied to my dataset I get NAs for some years. Either way, really useful.

Comment: Do you have any NA values in the opening column? I've only dealt with NA values in the closing column here.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally been able to come up with a solution that works for me.

Thanks a lot to everyone for the help, I learned a lot reading your solutions!

```
df_intermediate_1 <- c()
column_names <- c()

for(i in 1900:1905){
  new_column <- ifelse(df$opening <= i & df$closing > i, 1, 0)
  df_intermediate_1 <- cbind(df_intermediate_1, new_column)
  column_names <- cbind(column_names, paste0("Year_", i))}

colnames(df_intermediate_1) <- column_names

df_intermediate_2 <- cbind(df, df_intermediate_1)

index_years <- c()
for(i in 1900:1905){
  new_column <- paste0("Year_", i)
  index_years <- cbind(index_years, new_column)
}

df_intermediate_3 <- df_intermediate_2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(as.vector(index_years)),
               names_to = 'Year',
               values_to = 'is_open')

df_final <- df_intermediate_3 %>% 
  group_by(town, Year) %>% 
  summarise(stores = sum(is_open))

df_final$Year <- as.numeric(substr(df_final$Year, start = 6, stop = nchar(df_final$Year)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a “non-magical” solution (therefore relatively much code),
which can be supplemented in the future to select a range of years,
and possible error handling.

The idea is to create a zero data frame and add “real” values.

```
if (!require("pacman"))
  install.packages("pacman")

# install/load nedded library/ies
pacman::p_load(
  tidyr,
  dplyr
)



# create data
town <- c("A", "A", "A", "B")
opening <- as.Date(c("1900-01-01", "1905-02-05", "1906-01-01", "1910-01-01"))
closing <- as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, "1913-03-03"))

df <- data.frame(town, opening, closing)


# remove NA without opening, and closing cols
df %>%
  drop_na(!c(opening, closing)) -> df



get_result <- function(df)
{
  # get year from date
  get_year <- function(date)
    as.numeric(format(date, "%Y"))
  
  
  # create range of date by years
  get_range_years <- function(df)
  {
    years <- c(df$opening, df$closing)
    
    # get left year of range
    tryCatch(
      # if not all is NA
      {
        l_year <- get_year(min(years, na.rm = T))
      },
      error = function(e)
      {
        message("Error! It is impossible!")
        message(e)
        message("Hence return NA")
        
        return (NA)
      }
    )
    
    # get right year of range
    tryCatch(
      # if not all is NA
      {
        r_year <- get_year(max(years, na.rm = T))
      },
      error = function(e)
      {
        message("Error! Most of all NA")
        message(e)
        message("Hence right year from range is left year")
        
        r_year <- l_year
      }
    )
    
    l_year:r_year
  }
  
  
  # create helpfull variable
  range_years <- get_range_years(df)
  range_town <- sort(unique(df$town))
  
  len_years <- length(range_years)
  len_town <- length(range_town)
  
  
  # res df
  right_join(
    
    # base df
    df %>%
      
      # create variable as "year" = year of opening
      mutate(year = get_year(opening)) %>%
      
      # rename as in you
      rename(town_final = town) %>%
      
      # create groups by "town_final" and "year"
      group_by(town_final, year) %>%
      
      # for each groups calculate length
      summarise(stores = n()),
    
    # add "zero" df
    data.frame(
      year = rep(range_years, each = len_town),
      town_final = rep(range_town, len_years),
      stores = rep(0, len_years * len_town)
    ),
    by = c("town_final", "year")
  ) %>%
    
    mutate(stores = pmax(stores.x, stores.y, na.rm = T)) %>%
    select(!starts_with("stores.")) %>%
    arrange(town_final, year) %>%
    ungroup()
}

df_final <- get_result(df)
```

Output

```
print(df_final, n = nrow(df_final))
# A tibble: 28 × 3
   town_final  year stores
   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A           1900      1
 2 A           1901      0
 3 A           1902      0
 4 A           1903      0
 5 A           1904      0
 6 A           1905      1
 7 A           1906      1
 8 A           1907      0
 9 A           1908      0
10 A           1909      0
11 A           1910      0
12 A           1911      0
13 A           1912      0
14 A           1913      0
15 B           1900      0
16 B           1901      0
17 B           1902      0
18 B           1903      0
19 B           1904      0
20 B           1905      0
21 B           1906      0
22 B           1907      0
23 B           1908      0
24 B           1909      0
25 B           1910      1
26 B           1911      0
27 B           1912      0
28 B           1913      0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO roma. The OP requested counts of open stores _for each year_ so a record/row of open stores is required for _each year_.  Further, your sample data are not the same as the example given by the OP (although obviously their example output can't be achieved from their example which makes the question confusing). Some stores had not closed within the date range for each town (signified by NA in the OP). Please review the answers others have given for this question and consider revising yours to match what the OP requested. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I am still a beginner and learning English.

Comment: No problem. I'm a native English speaker and I still miss details in questions sometimes.