# Using a loop to create dummy variables in R

Tags: r

First, sorry if the question is something trivial but I am a beginner in R and I still find really difficult to do what I have in mind.

Basically I have a dataset with the dates of opening and closing for every town and I want to count the number of stores per town and year. I have previously posted this problem because I had no idea of how to do so and people were really helpful. In the end I was not able to implement none of the solutions people gave me but on the way of understanding them I learned a lot so I came up with my own way of doing it (which probably is not the best but I think that can work). My idea is: 1) to create a dummy variable for each year indicating if that year the store is open; 2) to use a pivot_longer() to obtain the data format that I need; 3) I group_by and summarise(). I try to do this manually (as in the example that I am going to show you), but I have observations from 1900 to 2023 and I wanted to use a loop to create the dummies but I don't know how to do it

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

id <- c("001", "002", "003", "004")
town <- c("A", "A", "A", "B")
opening <- as.Date(c("1900-01-01", "1902-02-05", "1903-01-01", "1903-01-01"))
closing <- as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, "1905-03-03"))

df <- data.frame(id, town, opening, closing)
```

This is what I do for a this example:

```
df_intermediate_1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Year_1900 = if_else(opening <= 1900 & closing > 1900, TRUE, FALSE),
         Year_1901 = if_else(opening <= 1901 & closing > 1901, TRUE, FALSE),
         Year_1902 = if_else(opening <= 1902 & closing > 1902, TRUE, FALSE),
         Year_1903 = if_else(opening <= 1903 & closing > 1903, TRUE, FALSE),
         Year_1904 = if_else(opening <= 1904 & closing > 1904, TRUE, FALSE),
         Year_1905 = if_else(opening <= 1905 & closing > 1905, TRUE, FALSE))

df_intermediate_2 <- df_intermediate_1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("Year_1900","Year_1901","Year_1902","Year_1903","Year_1904","Year_1905"),
    names_to = 'year',
    values_to = 'is_open')
  
df_output <- df_intermediate_2 %>% 
  group_by(town, year) %>% 
  summarise(stores = sum(is_open))

df_output$year <- as.numeric(substr(df_output$year, start = 6, stop = nchar(df_output$year)))
```

Comment: This isn't a good way to go about it.  Use the dplyr package to do the summarizing and  use the lubridate package to extract the year (which you can use as a part of your grouping collection).

Comment: What prevented you from implementing the answers provided in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76137974/counting-by-opening-and-closing-dates)? This looks like the same sample data.

Comment: What prevented me to implement the solutions from my previous question was that with my actual dataset the data was too large and it yielded an error (using the first solution) and that it created some NAs that I did not understand in the number of stores for some years (using the second solution).

Answer (score 0):

I have finally been able to come up with a solution that works for me.

Thanks a lot to everyone for the help.

```
df_intermediate_1 <- c()
column_names <- c()

for(i in 1900:1905){
  new_column <- ifelse(df$opening <= i & df$closing > i, 1, 0)
  df_intermediate_1 <- cbind(df_intermediate_1, new_column)
  column_names <- cbind(column_names, paste0("Year_", i))}

colnames(df_intermediate_1) <- column_names

df_intermediate_2 <- cbind(df, df_intermediate_1)

index_years <- c()
for(i in 1900:1905){
  new_column <- paste0("Year_", i)
  index_years <- cbind(index_years, new_column)
}

df_intermediate_3 <- df_intermediate_2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(as.vector(index_years)),
               names_to = 'Year',
               values_to = 'is_open')

df_final <- df_intermediate_3 %>% 
  group_by(town, Year) %>% 
  summarise(stores = sum(is_open))

df_final$Year <- as.numeric(substr(df_final$Year, start = 6, stop = nchar(df_final$Year)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).